# Interactive Structure Chart using Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to create a custom PowerBI visualization using python in jupyter notebook. This visualization is an organization hierarchy chart that can be displayed in normal hierarchy format, in network format and also a hierarchy with elbows.

The data in the hierarchy chart are entity codes like 1000, 1002... does anyone know how i can get started with this? I am thinking maybe plotly or Dash but i am not too familiar with these packages. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: find tutorials and learn both - to see which one is better for you. Stackoverflow is not place to write tutorials.